# Is there a way to serialize an ActiveRecord Relation object without loading it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, delayed-job

I am trying to export database rows to CSV depending on the parameters user picks. These exports can take a while, so I'm using delayed_job to process them and upload them to S3. My controller looks like this:

```
def search
  @books = visible_books.includes(:publisher)
  @books = @books.where(contract_id: assigned_contract_ids) if assigned_subscriber.present?
  @books = @books.unifilter(params, to_cents: ['total_cost'])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { export }
    format.js { @books.paginate(params[:page], per: 50) }
  end
end

def export
  exportable_books = ExportableBooks.new(@books)
  exportable_books.delay.upload
  render json: { id: exportable_books.id }
end
```

Unfortunately, `@books` can hold up to 10.000 rows, and when they are serialized to YAML for delayed_job, all those rows get loaded into memory, and then written to the database in YAML format. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Have you tried using `limit` and `offset`?

Comment: You could always try using something other than delayed_job to avoid the YAML serialization. For example, you could write your own cron job or use Resque (which may or may not have the same problem, I don't know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `delay` needs to serialize `exportable_books` into the database and `exportable_books` holds the complete result set of `@books`.

Instead of that you should initialize `ExportableBooks` just with the `params` and `assigned_contract_ids`, because that is much smaller when serialized. And then run the query in the `upload` method.

Comment: That is correct, but I then I would have duplicated query methods for the "regular" .js view and for the ExportableBooks. Also the queries use user session, which I would rather the ExportableBooks not know about.

Comment: Fair enough. But this is the way how DelayedJob works, it serializes data. Perhaps you want to try to generate the csv in the request and only upload the file delayed. I expect the csv to be reasonable faster and for sure it is faster to serialize one csv string instead of 10000 ActiveRecord objects.

Comment: I ended not using DelayedJob, but streaming the csv using ActionController::Live. But I agree with this solution, a serializable object responsible for filtering the books which doesn't get evaluated on serialization.